# React-Horizontal-Timeline: How to only display "year" label using getLabel

Tags: reactjs, date, datetime, timeline

React-Horizontal-Timeline requires input date as YYY-MM-DD but I only want to display YYYY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the docs, it looks like you need to provide a sorted list of dates in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. Then you write a `getLabel` function that React-Horizontal-Timeline can use to derive the label from those dates.

```
<HorizontalTimeline 
  values=['1984-10-10', '1985-11-10', '1986-10-10']
  getLabel={function(date) { return date.slice(0, 4); }}
  ...remaining props
/>
```

Here I am using the `.slice` method to extract `yyyy` from `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: Thank you @Ben, is there a way to display it 'July 2018' by having it spell out the month and as an integer for year?

Comment: No problem! You could extract the `mm` part of the string and convert it with a simple map. 01 goes to January, 02 goes to February, and so on